# override GetLayoutPage function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I tried to customize the engine view in my asp.net core application. So I added this snippet :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
            services.AddMvc();

            var webRootPath = _env.WebRootPath;
            string[] nwpath = webRootPath.Split('\\');
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < nwpath.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (i == nwpath.Length - 3) s += nwpath[i];
                else s += nwpath[i] + "\\";
            }

            var webSrcPath = s + @"\Application1";

            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine(webSrcPath));

        }
```

the `CustomViewEngine`

```
public class CustomViewEngine : System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine
{


    public CustomViewEngine(string NewPath)
    {
        var viewLocations = new[] {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
        "~/Views1/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
        Path.Combine(NewPath,"Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"), 
        Path.Combine(NewPath,"Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml") 

        // etc
    };

        this.PartialViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;
        this.ViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;

    }


}
```

When I run my application, I get this famous exception :

[image: exception]

Did I forget some thing?? because it seems that this function

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.GetLayoutPage(ViewContext context, string executingFilePath, string layoutPath)

is not overrided

How can I fix this ??

Comment: do you have view **_LayoutApp1.cshtml** in **Views>> Home** ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `RazorViewEngine` as base class for you custom view engine while in the code for registering `viewlocations` of Views, you are specifying the extension `.aspx` which is for WebForm view engine, change your base class to `WebFormViewEngine` or change the extension in the view locations for all paths to `.cshtml`

So Either change your class to inherit from `WebFormViewEngine`:

```
public class CustomViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
    { 
        public CustomViewEngine(string NewPath)
        {
            var viewLocations = new[] {
            "~/Views1/{1}/{0}.aspx",
            "~/Views1/{1}/{0}.ascx",
            "~/Views1/Shared/{0}.aspx",
            "~/Views1/Shared/{0}.ascx" ,
            Path.Combine(NewPath,"Views/{1}/{0}.aspx"),
             Path.Combine(NewPath,"Views/{1}/{0}.ascx"),
            Path.Combine(NewPath,"Views/Shared/{0}.aspx"),
            Path.Combine(NewPath,"Views/Shared/{0}.ascx")

            // etc
        };
```

or register the paths with razor view file extension which **csthml**:

```
    public class CustomViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
    { 
        public CustomViewEngine(string NewPath)
        {
            var viewLocations = new[] {
            "~/Views1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            Path.Combine(NewPath,"Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"),
            Path.Combine(NewPath,"Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"),

        };
```

Comment: thank you , I edit my code plz take a look ( I have the same pb after modification)